# Transfer function unity and output function poles are related?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

By solving a few examples, I found the pattern that, given a differential equation in $y(t)$ and $x(t)$, where $y(t)$ can be called the input and $x(t)$ the output, if we make the condition that $y(t) = x(t)$, and find the solution $y(t)$, then the poles of $Y(s)$ (the Laplace transform of $y(t)$), occur at the value of $s$ where the transfer function $H(s) = \frac {Y(s)} {X(s)}$ equals one. The transfer equals one because $y(t) = x(t)$ implies $Y(s) = X(s)$.

Any explanations why?

(NOTE: $s$ is complex)

As an example, try the differential equation $$y''(t) + 2y'(t) + 5y(t) = 3u'(t) + 12u(t)$$, where $u(t)$ is the input function.

Now substituting $u(t) = y(t)$, we get the differential equation whose solution is $$C_1 e^{\frac {1} {2}(1 - \sqrt{29})t} + C_2 e^{\frac {1} {2}(1 + \sqrt{29})t}$$

The poles of the Laplace transform are evidently at $$s = \frac {1} {2} (1 - \sqrt{29})$$ and $$s = \frac {1} {2} (1 + \sqrt{29})$$

But if we solved for $s$ such that $$H(s) = \frac {3s + 12} {s^2 + 2s + 5} = 1$$
we would have gotten the same values of $s$.

Comment: yes of course, if $\displaystyle\frac{\sum_{k=0}^K a_k (-s_0)^k}{\sum_{n=0}^N b_n (-s_0)^n} = 1$ then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^K a_k \frac{\partial^k}{\partial  t^k} e^{\textstyle -s_0 t } = \sum_{n=0}^N b_n \frac{\partial^n}{\partial t^n} e^{\textstyle -s_0 t }$ for every $t$

Comment: @user1952009, can you explain your answer a little more. I am a little confused about the notation. Thanks.

Comment: @user1952009, I don't follow half of your answer.

Comment: so this is really the basic fact of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus) which was the non-rigorous way, before the Laplace/Fourier transform was invented

Comment: and what don't you understand ? $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial t^k}$ ? it's just the $k$th derivative with respect to $t$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't understand the meaning of the terms. The first one looks like the transfer function, which you set to one. But I unclear about the second. Also, I don't see how exactly the first term is the ratio of output and input.

Comment: when you consider an homogenous linear differential equation $b_0 y(t) + b_1 y'(t) + b_2 y''(t) + \ldots = a_0 u(t) + a_1 u'(t) + a_2 u''(t) + \ldots$, once Laplace transformed, the transfer function is the quotient of two polynomials $H(s) = \frac{a_0 + a_1 (-s) + a_2 (-s)^2 + \ldots}{b_0 + b_1(-s)+b_2(-s)^2 + \ldots}$. finally if $H(s_0) = 1$ and  $u(t) =   e^{-s_0 t}$ then $y(t) = e^{-t s_0}$ will satisfy the differential equation

Comment: and note that in general, if $u(t) = e^{-s_0 t}$ then $y(t) = H(s_0) e^{-ts_0}$ will be solution of the differential equation, hence only when $H(s_0) = 1$ you will have the equality $y = u$